# how can I add border to thead?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on my project with flask and bootstrap.

The problem is, scrolled text pixel popped up above thead. like image below.

so I want to hide that by adding border to thead or making thead thicker than table row.

[image: my table]

here's my html code(Since code is too long, I skipped almost and took screenshot):
[image]

and my css code for scrollable table and clickable row:

```
.tableFixHead          { overflow-y: auto; height: 400px; }
.tableFixHead thead th { position: sticky; top: 0; }

table  { border-collapse: collapse; height: 400px; width: 100%; }
th { padding: 8px 16px; }
th { background:#eee; }
td tr { padding: 0;}
tbody { height: 400px; width: 100%;}

.clickable-row {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

how can I do?

++) added my html codes

```
                        <div class="tableFixHead">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-sm table-hover">
                            <thead>
                            <tr class="thead-light border">
                                <th>위치</th>
                                <th>퀘스트 이름</th>
                                <th>난이도</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            {% if quest_list %}
                                {% for quest in quest_list %}
                                    <tr class="clickable-row">
                                        <td>{{ quest.location }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ quest.name }}</td>
                                        <td align="center">{{ quest.difficulty }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% else %}
                                <p>퀘스트 목록을 불러올 수 없습니다.</p>
                            {% endif %}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </div>
```

Comment: hey  add code  you have images do add the codes also

Comment: @Aahad I added my html code thanx

Comment: you may also reset  coordonates `.tableFixHead thead th { position: sticky; top: -1px; }`

Comment: @G-Cyrillus ohh it worked. thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a top border to the `th` so it keeps its sticky positioning but looks thicker.

```
thead th {
   // use same background color to give illusion of no actual border
   border-top: 20px solid #eee;
   // if you want symmetry add 
   border-bottom: 20px solid #eee;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. but border-top and border-bottom move with the scroll. is there a way to fix border with thead?

Comment: not that i know of. maybe try repositioning the `td` instead of making `th` thicker. something like `tbody td { position: relative; top: 10px; }`

Answer (score 0):

.tableFixedHead table thead th {

border:5px solid #eee;
}